# CSS Keyframes on Webstories - Sintax Error for amp validator

Tags: asynchronous-messaging-protocol, amp-stories, custom-stories

I have built a webstory but i cant insert amp-keyframes on it.

The validator says i cant put amp-keyframe on the body because "" must have only one child: "".

But the documentation of webstories says the unique place i MUST place amp-keyframes is at "the last child of body" (`https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/websites/learn/spec/amphtml?redirected#keyframes-stylesheet`).

Im wondering if Google has blocked this "amp-keyframes" on the webstories.

Here is the CodePen with the code: `https://codepen.io/Luiz-Antonio-J-nior/pen/QWZpRRR`

The Amp Validator: `https://search.google.com/test/amp`

Anyone solved this?